# No encuentro el error de mi código html

Tags: php, html

Tengo este código HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>
 Alumno
</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#B8D1F1">
<?php
if (!(isset($_GET['varNumMat']))){
?>
 <form>
 <h1>Alumno</h1>
  NumMat: <input name="varNumMat" type="text" value="" >
  Nombre: <input name="varNombre" type="text" value="" >
  Apellido1: <input name="varApellido1" type="text" value="" >
  Apellido2: <input name="varApellido2" type="text" value="" >
 <input type="submit" value="Alta" />
 </form>
 <?php
}
else{
 $conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","root") or die("ERROR...");
 mysqli_select_db($conex,"GestionMat") or die("ERROR CON LA BASE DE DATOS");
 $NumMat = $_GET['varNumMat'];
 $Nombre = $_GET['varNombre'];
 $Apellido1 = $_GET['varApellido1'];
 $Apellido2 = $_GET['varApellido2'];
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,"INSERT INTO Alumno VALUES ('$NumMat','$Nombre','$Apellido1','$Apellido2')");
 if($resultado){
  echo " <b>Datos Insertados</b> ";
 }
 else{
  echo "Error en la insercion";
 }
 mysqli_close($conex);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero al mostrarlo en el navegador me aparece esta línea de abajo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían decirme qué error hay en el código para que no aparezca la línea de abajo? He revisado si me faltaba alguna comilla pero no he encontrado nada.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Los `if` deben ir dentro de un bloque como el siguiente `if (condicion) { //se cumple condición } else { //no se cumple condición}`, por ejemplo: `if($resultado) { echo " <b>Datos Insertados</b> "; } else { echo "Error en la insercion";}` Revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php), para más detalles.

Comment: @A.Cedano He añadido las llaves, pero sigo teniendo el mismo error

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon la nueva versión del código. Considera borrar caché y/o probar en modo incógnito del navegador.

Comment: @Excorpion Sí, ya lo he editado, pero me sigue saliendo igual.

Comment: @Excorpion Acabo de volver a copiar el código y me sigue saliendo exactamente igual que en la imagen. Tal vez sea un error mío aunque ya borré la caché y lo vi en modo incógnito.

Comment: De verdad yo creo que o hay comillas mal cerradas que no estamos viendo, o hay un echo extra, o no se... pero el error desde aca, no existe.

Comment: @Excorpion He eliminado el `<b>` y `</b>`  y ya no aparece la línea, no sé si es la solución correcta.

Comment: No era cuestión de `<b>` y `</b>`, más bien creo que no funcionaba al principio porque estaba en caché el código antiguo, pues usar etiquetas HTML es irrelevante para resolver este tipo de errores.